# Best practice? Const or "extends Component"?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

The syntax for React is evolving very fast and I was wondering what were the current best practices as of today, to declare a component, and what the differences it would make if I use an `extends component` or a `let` instead of a `const` (assuming `const` is the best option) to declare a new component. Would there be performance issues or something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: read this: http://jaketrent.com/post/smart-dumb-components-react/, this is more about stateful vs non, or smart vs dumb components...

Comment: Depends on whether you need React lifecycle events or not.

Comment: Actually I already read this before: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0
But it seems to me now that since no component is supposed (except inputs maybe) to contain any state or component property, const should be used every time. Right?

Comment: @Thanh-QuyNguyen State is not inherently bad. Let's say your component needs to fetch data from an API, and in most simple apps, you can just fetch the data from within your `componentDidMount` lifecycle method, and use `setState` when you data returns. You do not get lifecycle methods when using pure function components. So it really depends on _what_ you need your component to do.